# No module named 'django.core.context_processors' while I didn't use it anywhere

Tags: python, django

**This is my Views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import *


    def photoeditapp (request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            imgmdl = ImageEditModel()
            img = request.FILES.get('img')
            imgmdl.imagename = 'sample1'
            imgmdl.image = img
            imgmdl.save()
    return render(request, 'photoedit.html')
```

**Templates in settings.py**

```
    TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

**ERROR while running the server**

```
    ModuleNotFoundError at /photoedit/
    No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
```

**urls.py of the app**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('photoedit/', views.photoeditapp, name='photoedit'),
    ]
```

**I didn't use django.core.context_processors but it is till giving the error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your settings.py change

```
wrong:
   'django.core.context_processors.csrf',

correct:
    'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
```

the context_processors are no longer in core but in template